# JQuery for Preloading Images

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Okay so I have to make a website for my School's robotics team and I've installed a JQuery plugin for parallax scrolling, I learnt how to use it and frankly it was minimal use of JavaScript.

Although now I realized that my page is REALLY image heavy and it lags the site throughout the whole scrolling process, it just looks really bad. I've read many online descriptions for a preload, all with a similar layout although I still don't understand what I have to do.

Can anyone explain how a preload works and what information in what format I have to put it in?

Also if I was to have a preload loading interface, how would I integrate that? I have my .gif image, now what?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

why not use [lazy load plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using a jQuery Plugin, then just search for a jQuery Plugin which will preload images. One such plugin is [jQuery Image Preload Plugin](http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/)

This questions has also been answered already [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Comment: function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        // Alternatively you could use:
        // (new Image()).src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:
preload([
    'Contents/Backgrounds/BG1 Smaller.jpg',
    'Contents/Backgrounds/FRC.png',
    'Contents/Backgrounds/IMG_1732.JPG',
 'Contents/Backgrounds/IMG_1740.JPG',
 'Contents/Backgrounds/IMG_1747.JPG',
 'Contents/Backgrounds/NOBGTemp.png',
 'Contents/Backgrounds/Robotics4.jpg',
 'Contents/Backgrounds/Gallery BG.png'
]);

Like this? I'm sorry, I'm a noob >.<